# Automatic generation of Makevars and configure files

Tags: c++, statistics, rcpp, rcpp11

Friends,

Is there automatic way to generate `Makevars` and `configure`? I'm compiling my C++ code using the bash terminal with the **g++** compiler.

**Example**: I have the following code written using the `Rcpp.h` library where I use a `gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h` header file, that is, I use a library external to **Rcpp**.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double my_bessel(double x){
   return gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
}
```

In the example above, considering the configurations and path of the headers files of my computer, I can compile the above code using the code below in the bash terminal:

```
g++ -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG -I"/home/pedro/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/pedro/Dropbox/UFPB/Redes Neurais e Análise de Agrupamento/Rcpp" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -fpic  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt  -c program.cpp -o program.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -o program.so program.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/include/gsl -lR -lgsl -gslcblas -lm
```

Based on the settings and paths of the libraries on my computer, I am able to generate with the above code the object files and the .so file. However, as we know, these paths will not necessarily work when the function is compiled on a different machine than the package user. For this there are `Makevars` and `configure` files.

**Question**: Is there any way to automatically create the `Makevars` and `configure` files based on the above build statements?

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS +=`-O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic`
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`  
PKG_LIBS += `gsl-config --libs`
```

I created the `Makevars` file with the content just above. However, I'm not sure if there are ways to do this automatically using the build statements presented earlier.

Comment: Such a tool does not exist, and I would argue, is not needed (or feasible).  If you want to contribute one, make a proposal via an issue ticket at the GitHub repository.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [RcppGSL](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppgsl)? seems to take care of most of this for you.